# Export to Excel (Java List, HtmlDataTable, rich:dataTable)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

is there some simple way how to export Java List (or rich:dataTable or htmlDataTable, based on dataList) to formatted excel table?

datalist example:

```
private List<BDE> dataList;
session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory('R').openSession();   
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BDE.class);
  {some restrictions...}
dataList = criteria.list();
```

I'm abe export it to csv using [AnalysisTable](http://corpus.quran.com/java/example/csvexportexample.jsp), but it seems not to be much user friendly export..

Thank you

**UPDATE:** I've found primefaces solution and it really works. Rest of thing is, to create simple formatted xls table, don´t you have **some tip**?

Comment: Why don't you use apache poi ? It has good documentation and is widely used.

Comment: Yes, I've found it before. But It's a good tip - make the answer from your comment if you want. And in addition, If you place here some simle example (code), how to export data from dataTable to unformatted xls using POI, I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private List<BDE> dataList;
session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory('R').openSession();   
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BDE.class);
  {some restrictions...}
dataList = criteria.list();

//Excel creation after your dataList has been generated 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sth.xls");
//Give your file path may be to desktop so that you can see
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Row row = null;
Cell cell = null;
Sheet sheet1 = workBook.createSheet();
    for(int rowNo = 0;rowNo<dataList.size;rowNo++){
     row= sheet1.createRow(rowNo);
      for(int cellNo = 0;cellNo <2;cellNo++){//It would go to 0th and 1st row
        cell = row.createCell(cellNo);
            cell.setCellValue("Some of your value");
            }
    }
```